# XML, а точнее SVG и обработчик события JavaScript

Tags: xml, jquery, javascript, svg

Добрый вечер! Сейчас попытаюсь объяснить свою проблему. У меня есть SVG код такого вида:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->

    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="93mm" height="53mm">
        <color-profile name="acmecmyk" href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234"></color-profile>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="white"></rect>
            <g id="square">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart"></rect>
            </g>
            <use href="#square" transform="scale(2)"></use>
            <text x="20" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
            <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px" fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
    </svg>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы любые элементы нарисованные на холсте SVG можно было перемещать с помощью мыши. Я нашел подобное решение на JavaScript - [ТУТ](http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/events2/events2.xml), но хочу реализовать на jQuery. Помогите, если Вам не трудно. И еще вопрос - обязательно ли нужно код JavaScript или jQuery оборачивать в CDATA?

Comment: может стоит использовать инструменты по назначению: `Raphael.js` сделан специально, чтобы упростить работу с SVG, а jQuery оставьте манипуляции с DOM

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием, но есть одно но! Сроки сдачи работы поджимают, а в библиотеке Raphael.js еще нужно разобраться.

Comment: Можете преобразовать свой комментарий в ответ? Я его приму как лучший.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Базовый пример из документации [Element.drag](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag)

```
(function (r) {
    var x, y;
    r.circle(15, 15, 10).attr(fill).drag(function (dx, dy) {
        this.attr({
            cx: Math.min(Math.max(x + dx, 15), 85),
            cy: Math.min(Math.max(y + dy, 15), 85)
        });
    }, function () {
        x = this.attr("cx");
        y = this.attr("cy");
    });

})(prepare("Element.drag-extra"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще подключать код из внешнего файла:
    <script xlink:href="test.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Статья о манипуляции атрибутами элементов SVG посредством jQuery: http://svgmnemo.ru/pub/svgdyn.html